# Does Python have a similar View() function as R?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to learn Python for data science work coming from a Stata background. When I tried out R, I found a function View() that was similar to Stata's browse function that allowed me to display my data outside the console this way: [View(data) in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECi5N.png)

The View() function allows that data to be viewed as a spreadsheet rather than a console printout.

Are there any functions in Python that can show data as a table outside of the console? Thanks!

Comment: not by default as far as I know

Comment: Perhaps you would have better luck in attracting an answer to explain what `View()` does.

Comment: How about through other libraries?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what Python is.

Comment: All I can think of is Spyder (https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/), which is a scientific Python IDE that comes with a variable explorer (https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/variableexplorer.html) that achieves what you're asking. Running vanilla Python from console is probably very different from what you're used to.

Comment: Check out [rodeo](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo/) perhaps.